# How to do preorder traversal down a tree in java and print 0s and 1s to correspond with the certain characters at each node?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I've built my tree and have a certain character at each node. I would like to be able to print each character and next to it print 0s (for left) and 1s (for right) that correspond to the path of the tree that that certain character is at. So, if "a" is down the tree as right right left. It would print "a 110" I unfortunately cannot attach images of what exactly it should look like because this is my first question I have asked. However, here is my code so far. Any help is much appreciated!

```
 public static void printCodes(MsgTree root, String code)
  
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    printCodes(root.left, code + 1);
    
    printCodes(root.right, code + 1);
    
    System.out.println(root.payloadChar + "    " + code);
}


public static void main(String [] args)
{
    MsgTree tree = new MsgTree("^a^^!^dc^rb");
    
    System.out.println("character   code");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    
    printCodes(tree, "0");
    printCodes(tree, "1");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of attaching images you could show the tree in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

When you move left append `0` and when you move right append `1`.

```
printCodes(root.left, code + "0");
printCodes(root.right, code + "1");
```

Call it by passing an empty string for code.

```
printCodes(tree, "");
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. However, for the bottom right nodes of the tree it will print the corresponding numbers, but then also print two other numbers below it. So, for "c" it prints 1011, which is correct, but then prints 101 and then 10 before going onto the next node. Does this have something to do with my if statement?

Comment: You are doing a post order traversal. It visits all the children before visiting a node. If you want a different order, then you need to move the print statement first (for a pre-order traversal) or between the two recursive calls (for an in-order traversal)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong in your code is that when you are moving inside the tree, you must append to the code where are you moving to, so you only have to change that lines:

```
printCodes(root.left, code + "0");
    
printCodes(root.right, code + "1");
```

In addition, you should call the method by passing an empty string, because in root node you haven't moved yet

```
printCodes(tree, "");
```